# @WebServlet micrometer metrics uri value is coming as unknown

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, micrometer

uri value is coming as unknown when hitting spring boot servlet endpoint.

Below is the code snippet for my servlet endpoint.

```
@WebServlet("/api/service/*")
@Slf4j
public class ProxyServiceEndpoint extends GenericServlet {

  @Override
  public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = servletRequest.getParameterMap();
    log.info("sumit {}", parameterMap);

  }
}
```

And here you see the metrics generated by spring boot.

```
http_server_requests_seconds_max{application="my-app-2.0",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 0.005982392
```

Comment: Could you please try it with a controller instead?

Comment: @JonatanIvanov it's working with controller..but my requirement is with '@WebServlet'.. I need a generic controller which can receive any request like GET,PUT,POST..

Comment: You can open an issue against spring boot, I'm afraid this is not instrumented.

Comment: yesterday I thought about it..it will be challenging for them as there is no solid enpoint..its very much generic...in that case lots of metrics will be generated and may impact application performance. Only option I can think of creating custom metrics

Comment: I guess you can also use `@RequestMapping` on a controller method and specify multiple HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc) and has HttpServletRequest as a parameter for your controller method.